# List referencing

Tags: python, list

How can I reference some list values in python to others? (see example below)

```
my_list = [ 5, my_list[0] * 2, 25 - my_list[1] ]
print(my_list) # expected output: [5, 10, 15]
```

I am getting an error (it might be because I don't know how to do that)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    my_list = [ 5, my_list[0] * 2, 25 - my_list[1] ]
NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined
```

Comment: you're using a builtin class name as a variable name.

Comment: @deadvoid And in general, that's allowed, although it's a bad idea if you actually want to refer to the type later and you don't want to mislead other people reading your code.

Comment: @chepner I agree with you.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had accepted my answer before posting that comment.

Comment: @chepner I never said it's not allowed, nothing is _disallowed_ in python. I was pointing out that's one of his mistake in the exception from his pre edited code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; in general, the name on the LHS isn't bound to anything until after the RHS is done creating the value. (The error is coming from the fact that you are trying to reuse the name bound to the *type* `list` as the name of an *instance* of `list`. Don't do that.)

In Python 3.8, you can do the following, though I'm not sure what the benefit would be, aside from making it easier to edit part of the definition without rewriting the entire thing.

```
lst = [(y := 5), (z := y * 2), 25 - z]
```

A more straightforward definition that would work in *any* version of Python would just use a temporary variables:

```
y = 5
z = y * 2
lst = [y, z, 25 - z]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am looking for! Can you explain meaning of ```:=```?

Comment: It's an assignment *expression*, which, using `y := 5` as an example, binds `y` to the value `5` in the current scope and evaluates to the value itself.  Put another way, `foo := bar` evaluates to `bar` with the side effect of assigning the name `foo` to the value  `bar`. Since the list definition is processed from left to right, `y` is guaranteed to be defined when `z := y * 2` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below was valid for the question before the author edited it.

The author tried to do something like this:

```
list = [5, list[0] * 2, 25 - list[1]]
```

Instead of an answer he got

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

First, `list` is already used for the Python builtin `list`, and while this is technically possible, you should not use it as a variable name.

That said, in the first line, you use reference `list[0]`. As `list` was not used to define the variable for your list before, this `list` refers to the builtin `list` keyword.

As the error message explains, you can't access the builtin `list` by index.

Comment: `list` is not reserved; if it were (like `if`), it would be a syntax error to even *try* to use it as a variable name. `list` is merely an ordinary identifier already in use.

Comment: And as a result, `list` *was* defined before, but `list[0]` is not, because the type `list` is not indexable.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the terminology - indeed, list is not a reserved keyword, but an already used variable name. I updated my answer. As of your second comment - this is wrong. Please try it in a repl.

Comment: No, `list` is *absolutely* defined; `list[0]` doesn't raise a `NameError`, it raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: `list[0]` is not indexable as list refers to the builtin list type (in the posters original question) - that is why he got an `TypeError` - nobody talked of a `NameError`. So I guess it is all okay now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Saying `list` was not defined implicitly asserts a `NameError`, as that's what you get when you try to use an undefined name.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference variables before you create them, but you could add the element sequentially to the list like

```
my_list = [ 5 ]
my_list.append(my_list[0] * 2)
my_list.append(25 - my_list[1])
print(my_list) # expected output: [5, 10, 15]
```

(Note that I've also changed the name of your variable, because `list` is a built in class name).